# Repository Pattern without OR Mapper - Accessing of Attributes

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have a aggregate root called "Billing Document" which has some additional entities as attributes ("Billing lines").
I want to persist these objects together into my database. I read about the repository pattern in combination with a mapperclass. this would be a good solution in my eyes. My domain objects don't need to know anything about persistence. The repository should save the "billing document" and the "billing lines" together in a consistent state. Note that I'm not able to use some kind of OR-Mapper here.

The attributes to be mapped and persisted are private attributes. So by default also the repository and the mapper don't have access to them.
What is a good solution to grant access to these attributes so the data could be persisted? I don't really want to add special methods to my domain objects that are only needed by persistence. This could lead to the problem that there methods would maybe be used also in other contexts.

1) Should I implement a method called "getContractData" or "toDatabase" which returns the attributes of the "Billing Document" and the corresponding "Billing Lines" as a structure and the mapper could use this structure.
2) Should I give my repository and mapper a special "friends" status, so they can directly access private attributes?

Comment: What kind of querying do you need? Could you just serialize the whole BillingDocument structure to JSON (including the private fields) and store it as one block of JSON in the database for your 'save' operation? If the serializer you chose knows how to get to the BillingLines, for both serialization and de-serialization, then I'd just use that.

Comment: good idea, but it's a relational database I need to save to.

Comment: @davidmayer  Which one? SQL Server has tremendous JSON query capability now. You can even store JSON and have a query that translates a JSON property collection into a normal-looking SQL rowset.

Comment: Discarding the JSON option though, the simplest solution would be to add a method to produce a DTO of the BillingLineItems specifically for the persistance layer. Make sure to give it a comment that its only usage should be the persistance module and make it scary enough to ward off any unintended usages. If those occur later, its not your fault.